# How to avoid mongo with rails generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, database

I have rails app with mongoDB and Postgres. I have installed mongoid so whenever I use `rails g model MYMODEL`, it's generate model with mongo config. Can anyone faced similar issue. How to suppress the mongo config ?

Comment: can you tell whats in your config/database.yml file, also what do you have for `Database adapter` in `$ bin/rake about`
?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which ORM you need to create your model like this:

```
rails g active_record:model MyModel
```

or

```
rails g mongoid:model MyModel
```

You can use for it for other generators (migrations at least)

Answer (score 1):

You can force your generator to use specific ORM

```
rails g model MyModel --orm=postgresql
```

Note: *that might be `postgres` not `postgresql`. Can't remember exactly. Try both.*